# Boost Thread - Create a Thread without join()

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-thread

I have an application that creates a thread, and it will be listening for incoming connections. And the main thread will be doing other things.

```
boost::mutex mutex;
void
ThreadFunction(int port, int(*callbackFunc)(int, int))
{
    mutex.lock();
    std::cout << "Cannot get to this point" << std::endl;
    mutex.unlock();
    Application app;
    app.run(port, callbackFunc);
}

void 
Init(int port, int(*callbackFunc)(int, int))
{
    std::cout << callbackFunc(1,1) << std::endl;
    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&ThreadFunction, port, callbackFunc));
}

int
main(){
    int port = 2340;
    Init(port, *callbackfunction);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am having is that it never access the `std::cout << "Cannot get to this point" << std::endl;` However, if I call join() after I create the thread, it works just fine but then it is blocking the application.

What do I need to do for the thread call the ThreadFunction?

Comment: Just an addition, I believe the standard's says that `terminate()` will be called when an `std::thread` is destructed. Boost's implementation calls `detach()` instead, but it may change to conform with the standard in the future, so it's probably not a good idea to let it go out of scope like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application terminates (by leaving main()) before the thread gets a chance to do its work. Once you implement a wait-for-connections loop, the problem will be resolved. So, no need to do anything.

Comment: Another quick question, I am listening for incoming connections when I call the Application::run() method, however, it is exiting; is it exiting becayse I don't give enough time to start the server? Will the application keep running if a secondary thread is blocking?

Comment: @Takashi-kun: The application will quit as soon as someone calls `exit` - which main does when it returns.